# STM32 Virtual EEPROM Page Swap not working correctly

Tags: stm32, flash

I try to save a look up table in the flash memory by using the virtual eeprom library from STM32. I chose a page size of 3kByte to save all the data and it works good until the page is full. Then, the routine EE_PageTransfer(VirtAddress, Data); is called nonstop when new data is written and it throws always an error. Inside this routine, page 1 seems always to be the valid page, that need to be copied to page 0 and this fails. After reboot, the EE_Init() function throws an error and does not recover, until a full flash erease is done.

Does anyone know whats wrong here? Is there a bug in the STM32 EEPROM library?

I attached my settings from the eeprom.h library and the function EE_PageTransfer() below. I could not add the whole eeprom.c file, because it is too big. If someone knows how to upload source files correctly here, please let me know.

Edit: I got a first idea what it could be. At first, the page 0 is copied correctly and it seems to transfer the page. But then after 1kbyte is written to page 1, the PageFull error comes again, and not after 3kbyte as it should be. From then, always a page full error is thrown. Is there a bug somewhere in the library?

**Edit 2:** It seems like the library is just not made for page sizes other than 2kByte, but I'm sure this can be changed somehow. I will try to figure out how to. With 2kByte page size everything works fine.

eeprom.h:

```
/* Define to prevent recursive inclusion -------------------------------------*/
#ifndef __EEPROM_H
#define __EEPROM_H

/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "stm32f3xx_hal.h"

/* Exported constants --------------------------------------------------------*/
/* EEPROM emulation firmware error codes */
#define EE_OK      (uint32_t)HAL_OK
#define EE_ERROR   (uint32_t)HAL_ERROR
#define EE_BUSY    (uint32_t)HAL_BUSY
#define EE_TIMEOUT (uint32_t)HAL_TIMEOUT

/* Base address of the Flash sectors */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_0   ((uint32_t)0x08000000) /* Base @ of Page 0, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_1   ((uint32_t)0x08000800) /* Base @ of Page 1, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_2   ((uint32_t)0x08001000) /* Base @ of Page 2, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_3   ((uint32_t)0x08001800) /* Base @ of Page 3, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_4   ((uint32_t)0x08002000) /* Base @ of Page 4, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_5   ((uint32_t)0x08002800) /* Base @ of Page 5, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_6   ((uint32_t)0x08003000) /* Base @ of Page 6, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_7   ((uint32_t)0x08003800) /* Base @ of Page 7, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_8   ((uint32_t)0x08004000) /* Base @ of Page 8, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_9   ((uint32_t)0x08004800) /* Base @ of Page 9, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_10  ((uint32_t)0x08005000) /* Base @ of Page 10, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_11  ((uint32_t)0x08005800) /* Base @ of Page 11, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_12  ((uint32_t)0x08006000) /* Base @ of Page 12, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_13  ((uint32_t)0x08006800) /* Base @ of Page 13, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_14  ((uint32_t)0x08007000) /* Base @ of Page 14, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_15  ((uint32_t)0x08007800) /* Base @ of Page 15, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_16  ((uint32_t)0x08008000) /* Base @ of Page 16, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_17  ((uint32_t)0x08008800) /* Base @ of Page 17, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_18  ((uint32_t)0x08009000) /* Base @ of Page 18, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_19  ((uint32_t)0x08009800) /* Base @ of Page 19, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_20  ((uint32_t)0x0800A000) /* Base @ of Page 20, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_21  ((uint32_t)0x0800A800) /* Base @ of Page 21, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_22  ((uint32_t)0x0800B000) /* Base @ of Page 22, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_23  ((uint32_t)0x0800B800) /* Base @ of Page 23, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_24  ((uint32_t)0x0800C000) /* Base @ of Page 24, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_25  ((uint32_t)0x0800C800) /* Base @ of Page 25, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_26  ((uint32_t)0x0800D000) /* Base @ of Page 26, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_27  ((uint32_t)0x0800D800) /* Base @ of Page 27, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_28  ((uint32_t)0x0800E000) /* Base @ of Page 28, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_29  ((uint32_t)0x0800E800) /* Base @ of Page 29, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_30  ((uint32_t)0x0800F000) /* Base @ of Page 30, 2 Kbytes */
#define ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_31  ((uint32_t)0x0800F800) /* Base @ of Page 31, 2 Kbytes */


/* Define the size of the sectors to be used */
#define PAGE_SIZE               (uint32_t)FLASH_PAGE_SIZE  /* Page size */ //Now 6kByte -> HEX 0x1800

/* EEPROM start address in Flash */
#define EEPROM_START_ADDRESS  ((uint32_t)ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_26) /* EEPROM emulation start address */

/* Pages 0 and 1 base and end addresses */
#define PAGE0_BASE_ADDRESS    ((uint32_t)(EEPROM_START_ADDRESS + 0x0000))
#define PAGE0_END_ADDRESS     ((uint32_t)(EEPROM_START_ADDRESS + (PAGE_SIZE - 1)))

#define PAGE1_BASE_ADDRESS    ((uint32_t)(ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_29))
#define PAGE1_END_ADDRESS     ((uint32_t)(ADDR_FLASH_PAGE_29 + PAGE_SIZE - 1))

/* Used Flash pages for EEPROM emulation */
#define PAGE0                 ((uint16_t)0)
#define PAGE1                 ((uint16_t)1) /* Page nb between PAGE0_BASE_ADDRESS & PAGE1_BASE_ADDRESS*/

/* No valid page define */
#define NO_VALID_PAGE         ((uint16_t)0x00AB)

/* Page status definitions */
#define ERASED                ((uint16_t)0xFFFF)     /* Page is empty */
#define RECEIVE_DATA          ((uint16_t)0xEEEE)     /* Page is marked to receive data */
#define VALID_PAGE            ((uint16_t)0x0000)     /* Page containing valid data */

/* Valid pages in read and write defines */
#define READ_FROM_VALID_PAGE  ((uint8_t)0x00)
#define WRITE_IN_VALID_PAGE   ((uint8_t)0x01)

/* Page full define */
#define PAGE_FULL             ((uint16_t)0x1800)

/* Variables' number */
#define NB_OF_VAR             ((uint16_t)1536)  //Half a page, since Address will also be safed -> always uint32_t

/* Exported types ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Exported macro ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Exported functions ------------------------------------------------------- */
uint16_t EE_Init(void);
uint16_t EE_ReadVariable(uint16_t VirtAddress, uint16_t* Data);
uint16_t EE_WriteVariable(uint16_t VirtAddress, uint16_t Data);

#endif /* __EEPROM_H */

/************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

PageTransfer():

```
static uint16_t EE_PageTransfer(uint16_t VirtAddress, uint16_t Data)
{
  HAL_StatusTypeDef flashstatus = HAL_OK;
  uint32_t newpageaddress = EEPROM_START_ADDRESS;
  uint32_t oldpageid = 0;
  uint16_t validpage = PAGE0, varidx = 0;
  uint16_t eepromstatus = 0, readstatus = 0;
  uint32_t page_error = 0;
  FLASH_EraseInitTypeDef s_eraseinit;

  /* Get active Page for read operation */
  validpage = EE_FindValidPage(READ_FROM_VALID_PAGE);

  if (validpage == PAGE1)       /* Page1 valid */
  {
    /* New page address where variable will be moved to */
    newpageaddress = PAGE0_BASE_ADDRESS;

    /* Old page ID where variable will be taken from */
    oldpageid = PAGE1_BASE_ADDRESS;
  }
  else if (validpage == PAGE0)  /* Page0 valid */
  {
    /* New page address  where variable will be moved to */
    newpageaddress = PAGE1_BASE_ADDRESS;

    /* Old page ID where variable will be taken from */
    oldpageid = PAGE0_BASE_ADDRESS;
  }
  else
  {
    return NO_VALID_PAGE;       /* No valid Page */
  }

  /* Set the new Page status to RECEIVE_DATA status */
  flashstatus = HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_HALFWORD, newpageaddress, RECEIVE_DATA);  
  /* If program operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
  if (flashstatus != HAL_OK)
  {
    return flashstatus;
  }

  /* Write the variable passed as parameter in the new active page */
  eepromstatus = EE_VerifyPageFullWriteVariable(VirtAddress, Data);
  /* If program operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
  if (eepromstatus != HAL_OK)
  {
    return eepromstatus;
  }

  /* Transfer process: transfer variables from old to the new active page */
  for (varidx = 0; varidx < NB_OF_VAR; varidx++)
  {
    if (varidx != VirtAddress)  /* Check each variable except the one passed as parameter */
    {
      /* Read the other last variable updates */
      readstatus = EE_ReadVariable(varidx, &DataVar);
      /* In case variable corresponding to the virtual address was found */
      if (readstatus != 0x1)
      {
        /* Transfer the variable to the new active page */
        eepromstatus = EE_VerifyPageFullWriteVariable(varidx, DataVar);
        /* If program operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
        if (eepromstatus != HAL_OK)
        {
          return eepromstatus;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  s_eraseinit.TypeErase   = FLASH_TYPEERASE_PAGES;
  s_eraseinit.PageAddress = oldpageid;
  s_eraseinit.NbPages     = 1;

  /* Erase the old Page: Set old Page status to ERASED status */
  flashstatus = HAL_FLASHEx_Erase(&s_eraseinit, &page_error);  
  /* If erase operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
  if (flashstatus != HAL_OK)
  {
    return flashstatus;
  }

  /* Set new Page status to VALID_PAGE status */
  flashstatus = HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_HALFWORD, newpageaddress, VALID_PAGE);   
  /* If program operation was failed, a Flash error code is returned */
  if (flashstatus != HAL_OK)
  {
    return flashstatus;
  }



  /* Return last operation flash status */
  return flashstatus;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The STM32 flash that you're interfacing with has an inherent page size. This page size reflects the physical organization of the flash memory and cannot be changed. On STM32F3 devices, this page size is 2KB. You can only erase an entire hardware page at a time -- there is no way to partially erase a page.

Redefining the page size to 3KB in code will not work. The hardware page size is still 2KB, and a call to `HAL_FLASHEx_Erase()` will erase a 2KB page of flash based on the hardware page number. This will end up erasing the wrong data entirely.

You could potentially use a virtual page size of 4KB (2 x 2KB), but you will need to make some changes to the EEPROM emulation code to support this. In particular, you will need to call `HAL_FLASHEx_Erase()` twice -- once for each physical page.

Comment: Thank you, luckily in the next iteration i change to an STM32F4 which seems to have 16kByte page sizes naturally, enough for my project.